# Is there any way to get the user details from aws cognito without using AWS_KEY_ID And AWS_SECRET_KEY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-php-sdk

Im using aws cognito and php sdk for user authentication and on website I want to list all the user names from cognito since I didn't saved the names in the database. The problem is I don't have aws key id and secret id. But i have pool id, client id and client secret key. Is there any way to fetch the details?

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of access with AWS Cognito rights. From client side you can't query all the users so you have to query them from server-side. Good part that you're using PHP SDK. If your PHP application is running on any AWS compute service like **EC2** or **Lambad** then you don't need IAM Access Keys. You can use `IAM Roles` and attach the role with the services (EC2, Lambda, etc.) IAM roles behave same as Access Keys.

Sample code to list users in PHP can be found in the documentation below:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cognito-idp-2016-04-18.html#listusers